# Binding events with Hammer.js and .on()

Tags: jquery, web-applications, touch

[Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/) adds javascript touch and gesture support to my web app. My problem lies in using .hammer() with DOM elements that do not exist until an .ajax() call on document ready.

Previously, I've used something like:

```
$('#parent').on('click', '.child', function(e){
    $(this).hammer()...
});
```

But, I need to be able to bind the event with Hammer without calling .on() as the .on() event types do not match the Hammer event types. Any help is appreciated - I'm by no means a jQuery genius, nor am I very familiar with event binding.

Comment: You can probably use custom events - http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-custom-events-they-will-rock-your-world/

Comment: Hammer is already a custom event library of sorts. My problem is binding the Hammer events to .ajax()-created elements. I need events for my events?

Comment: I found some code on the Hammer doc site where you should be able to change bind() to on() - $("#element")
   .hammer({
        // options...
   })
   .bind("tap", function(ev) {
        console.log(ev);
   });

Comment: By that logic, I tried `$('#parent').hammer().on('drag', '.child', function(ev) { console.log(ev); });` with no luck. Is that what you were thinking?

Comment: Yeah, something along those lines.I used hammer for a project recently, but didn't have to worry about binding on dynamically (Ajax) loaded content. You may also want to look at $.getScript()

Comment: What do you mean by *as the .on() event types do not match the Hammer event types*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [jquery.hammer.js](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/master/jquery.hammer.js) source, you should have no problem delegating events.

```
$("#parent").on("doubletap",".child",dostuff);
```

just make sure you call `.hammer()` on the elements when you add them to your page.

Comment: I was able to get this to work with a combination of Kevin and Jay's suggestions, but the propagation/parent-child-bubbling issues in Hammer are too much to deal with for me. I'm going to try jGestures. Thank you both.

Answer (score 6):

## Give toe.js a try

A by [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/) inspired library is [toe.js](https://github.com/visiongeist/toe.js), which uses the jQuery special events API where Hammer.js uses a custom implementation.

So without any further initialization on your elements you should be able to use it like:

```
$('#parent').on('tap', '.child', function(e){
  // ... Do something
});
```

I've switched to toe.js because backbone.js uses the standard jQuery events API.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, toe.js helped me a lot! I used it to bind touch event listeners to image map areas on mobile Safari, Hammer.js didn't work for that purpose.