# bind jquery datepicker open trigger to 'touchStart' instead of 'focus'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm sure it's doable, but i'm not sure how to do it.
Currently:
jquery datepicker is binded to the focus event (which in my case is bad for iPad force keyboard opening on input focus).
i want to bind the datepicker to 'touchStart' like:

> $('#date').datepicker({trigger : 'touchStart'});

Please Advice

Answer (score 0):

you should use Hammer.js for gestures, something like:

```
 var d = new DatePicker(function(element, handler) {
            Hammer(element, {
                drag : false,
                transform : false
            }).on('tap', handler, false);
        }, {
            backdrop : true
        });
```

there is another option, of binding the events, see:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692194/binding-events-with-hammer-js-and-on](http://Binding%20events%20with%20Hammer.js%20and%20.on())

Comment: I never tried Hammer.js, but unfortunately i can't replace Hammer.js with jquery.datepicker.js at this phase of the project, so i need to find a solution for datepicker. (i'm stuck with it) :S

Comment: @Roshdy, hammer.js is used for gesture events, and you can use it to attach a certain gesture event to another event, it is not a replacement for the jquery.datepicker

Comment: I'll give it a try then